# Choose a file sporadic issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, windows-7-x64, node-webkit

I am using `AngularJS` in a `Nodewebkit` application to upload a file.
HTML has :

```
 <input type="file" id="fileInput" class="image-selector" name="image" accept="image/*" />
```

In desktop application, on clicking "Choose File" there are some sporadic issues which occur in windows:
   1. It does not show all folders in a specific location.
   2. If there are two windows users A and B, if User A is logged in currently, it shows Desktop/Documents foloder of User B instead of A.

This happened only once every 10-15 times I clicked on Choose File.
I am not sure sure If issue is related to nodewebkit or javascript or windows.